# Exception trying to load powerpoint presentation

Tags: c#, exception, powerpoint, office-interop

I have a program that I need c# to load a powerpoint presentation.  when I do the following it throws an exception

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] = {"Presentation (unknown member) : Object does not exist."}

It happens on `pres.SlideShowWindow.View.First()`.  I also tried `pres.SlideShowWindow.Activate()` before this but then got the exception on activate.  At the Run line the powerpoint flashes on the screen for just a second and I can make out the slide before it leaves.  What am I doing wrong?

```
try
{
   app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
   app.SlideShowNextSlide += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication_SlideShowNextSlideEventHandler(app_SlideShowNextSlide);
   pres = app.Presentations.Open(filename,
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);
   pres.SlideShowSettings.Run();
   pres.SlideShowWindow.View.First();
 }
 catch (Exception f)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(f.Message);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out

```
app.SlideShowNextSlide += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.EApplication_SlideShowNextSlideEventHandler(app_SlideShowNextSlide);
```

was being fired even on `pres.SlideShowWindow.View.First();` which was unexpected.  I was hoping it only fired on `pres.SlideShowWindow.View.Next();` but that was not the case. Because of logic in `app_SlideShowNextSlide()` the slideshow was closed before it got to the first slide thus causing the Exception.